# Struggling with a conversion. Showing number of atoms per cubic meter using pressure in Torr

Tags: pressure, atoms, ideal-gas

I have been trying to show that the following is true:

N = 9.65 x 10^24 x (P/T)

Where N is the number of atoms per cubic meter of an ideal gas at pressure P (in Torr) and temperature T (in Kelvin).

I started with the ideal gas law PV=nRT and tried to find a way to equate R with the constant given in the equation above - however, I keep getting answers that do not match up with 9.65 x 10^24.

Have I started this problem correctly, or is there another way that I should be attacking this?

Comment: You need to be consistent in the use of your measuring units. While it's possible to use $\text{Torr}$ as a unit for pressure, did you also use a $\text{Torr}$ based value for $R$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your starting point should be that $24.789 598 \,\mathrm{dm^3}$ of ideal gas contains $1 \text{ mol}$ of atoms (or molecules) at $298 \,\mathrm{K}$ and $100 \text{ kPa}$ and that $1 \text{ mol}$ contains $6.022140857 \times 10^{23}$ atoms (or molecules), that is Avogadro's constant.

Then, using the Ideal Gas Law, develop your $N,p,T$ relationship, using S.I. units.

Finally, if you want to use $\mathrm{m^3}$ and $\text{ Torr}$ as units of volume and pressure, simply convert from $\mathrm{dm^3}$ and $\mathrm{kPa}$.

Comment: So I "fixed" some of the markup related to units in your post. The way you were doing it with `\text{}` for some units, but not for those that needed powers was inconsistent. I used my preferred style (like `\,\mathrm{m/s^2}`), but there are other who have different preferences. See http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4233 http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/7136 for some notes on other choices and http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/54885 to the recommendations of standards bodies.

Comment: @dmckee: thank you. I learned LaTex quite easily but never really mastered units with powers. The text tag doesn't work for that. I'll book mark your links and study them. I edit quite a quite a few questions myself, so now I should be able to do that properly too.